# Show Keys on Screen

Tags: windows, keyboard

Does anyone know of a program that will **show the keyboard buttons you are pressing on the screen**? I would like to know if it exists for windows :)

I ask because I would like them to appear as I do video tutorials.

Comment: Heh. I was wondering about this myself today. I was going to write an AutoHotkey script if I couldn't find a decent solution. :)

Comment: This question seems to be pretty close to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529329/how-to-display-pressed-keyboard-shortcuts-on-screen-during-presentations-or-scre) on StackOVerflow. Also, [KeyViz](http://chickensoft.com/tools.php) is a freeware program that can do this too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Keypose](http://katastrophos.net/magnus/blog/2008/08/01/keypose-flavour-your-screencasts-with-shortcuts/) is exactly what you have described!